# Is there a Computer Modern font which contains all the math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, computer-modern

I downloaded the **Computer Modern Serif** font, which is the default LaTeX font, to use it on my website, but when I opened the file with FontForge I noticed that it misses a lot of math symbols. It contains just the basic math symbols, such as + - : = < > and few others.

I download the font files from many sources but they seems to be all the same.

For example, the sign "not equal" `≠` is missing and if I write it in the site editor, what then is displayed is the default font symbol instead (Times New Roman I think). I tried typing `≠`, `&#x2260;`, `&#8800;`, `&ne;` but the result is always the same.

Here you can see a comparison of my site output and the latex output. As you can see all the letters and the 3 are displayed correctly (same font), while the "not equal" symbol is not (different fonts).

[image]

If you would like to inspect the file you can download it [here](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/Computer%20Modern%20Serif.zip), then open the file `cmunrm.woff` which corresponds to the normal style.

I know that it is possible to add glyphs to a font using FontForge, but in this way I will have manually obtain an `svg` file for each symbol that I need and then add it to the font, which seems a long way.

I'm looking on CTAN if there is a font containing more than just the basic math symbols, somebody knows if such a font file exists?

I tried all the `otf` files on CTAN `fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf` but none of them contains the math symbols.

p.s. I hope this is not off-topic on this board

Comment: I am afraid that the only common of your question with TeX and friends is its font, and thus may be it is offtopic... but sure someone will help you at least by telling where to ask such a question.

Comment: Minimal example please.

Comment: The font `cmsy` contains many more "text size" symbols, and `cmex` the "oversize" ones.  But more symbols have been defined that aren't there.  Remember that the "basic" TeX fonts contain only 128 characters each.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks could you link to the proper `cmsy` you are talking about? Because I tried with the `cmsy` files from `https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf` but they just contain the alphabet.

Comment: you could check https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm-math, that's an opentype math font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow that's the Holy Grail of math symbols! Thank you!

Comment: There is also a font update called `newcomputermodern`. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern?lang=en